# Cannot create login MVVM architecture

Tags: android, mvvm

I decided to create a small application, which uses MVVM architecture. I need to create a login flow. I use fragment as view and here's a part of its code:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        when (it) {
            Result.Loading -> {
                println("Loading")
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                println(it.data)
            }
            Result.Error -> {
                println("Error")
            }
        }
    })

    log_in_button.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.logInUser("Sergei", "12345")
    }

}
```

Here I subscribe on the user updates and set button's listener.
Here's my ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val loginRepository = LoginRepository()

    private var login: String = ""
    private var password: String = ""

    fun logInUser(login: String, password: String) {
        loginRepository.fetchUser(login, password)
    }

    val user: LiveData<Result<String>>
        get() = loginRepository.fetchUser(login, password)
            .asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)

}
```

I did is as I saw in the tutorial, where the author advised to create a getter, which will call a repository's fetch user method. And here's my Repository class:

```
class LoginRepository {

    fun fetchUser(login: String, password: String) = flow {
        emit(Result.Loading)
        if (login == "Sergei" && password == "12345") {
            emit(Result.Success("Sergei"))
        } else {
            emit(Result.Error)
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know if it's correct to use flow here, as I don't have the flow of users, but I use it as I emit several Results. Please, tell me, if it's a wrong decision to use flow here.

So, and my problem that I don't understand how to update the user in `ViewModel` class after getting data from the Repository's fetch user method, please help me to solve this problem. I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

** UPD **

I modified my repository and viewmodel in the following way:

```
class LoginRepository(private val user: MutableLiveData<Result<User>>) {

    fun fetchUser(login: String, password: String) = run {
        if (login == "Sergei" && password == "12345") {
            user.postValue(Result.Success(User(login, password)))
        }
    }

}

class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var user: MutableLiveData<Result<User>> = MutableLiveData()

    private val loginRepository = LoginRepository(user)

    fun logInUser(login: String, password: String) {
        loginRepository.fetchUser(login, password)
    }

}
```

This implementation works correctly but are there any moments to improve?

Comment: In general, you would use the `postValue()` method to update live data: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#postValue(T)
Note that you shouldn't use separate login/password fields in the ViewModel, so get rid of those.  Your `fetchUser()` method should return a user object instead of separate strings.

Comment: @DanielNugent, updated the question